# Third monitor not recognized on USB-c after latest updates on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a Levnovo T480s with Intel UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT20) and I had two monitors connected one via the onboard HDMI and another using a USB-c to HDMI adapter.

Until yesterday everything was working fine. This morning when I started my computer I noticed that Ubuntu was installing some software updates and while it was loading I could the Ubuntu logo and loading spinner on all three screens. However, after the updates finished, the monitor connected to the USB-c is not being recognized anymore.

For the life of me, I have tried every possible issue+solution I could find on the internet and still nothing. I have tried swapping the connections, changing HDMI cable, and even reinstalling drivers and still, I cannot get the screen to be recognized.
Any takers on a different solution?

Comment: what happens if you boot from a bit older live cd/usb ?