# after Kubuntu 20.04 auto update all monitors not recognized correct (default)

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, kde

after Kubuntu auto update all monitors not recognized anymore.

1. if i boot from Linux Boot CD (on week older version) everything looks  very good (2 monitors and good resulution)
2. then i start the recovery mode
3. i got only 1 Monitor with 1024x768 and no name for it (second monitor is off)

In addition, I noticed that the configuration of the scceenshot tool was reset to the default values. I usually only take a photo of a selected area using the print button (this can be easily reconfigured, but it's strange and doesn't feel good).

## question / anwers sound a bit simular:

[After installing NVIDIA drivers, I boot into a black screen [13.10]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372686/after-installing-nvidia-drivers-i-boot-into-a-black-screen-13-10) (  7 years ago )

[Third monitor not recognized on USB-c after latest updates on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313792/third-monitor-not-recognized-on-usb-c-after-latest-updates-on-ubuntu-20-04)

## my system:

Kubuntu 20.04
KDE-Plasma-Version: 5.18.5
KDE-Frameworks-Version: 5.68.0
Qt-Version: 5.12.8
Kernel-Version: 5.8.0-45-generic

[image: wrong monitor. called default]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i reused the good anser here from 2013 https://askubuntu.com/a/373573/1017209
with a very little update.

i could not answer what happens while this update was running last night, but this helps.

this did not solve the little other problem with the configuration of the scceenshot tool. My guess is that there might have been a brief power outage while the system was shutting down.

1. remove all nvidia bits
2. install the correct drivers:
3. reboot

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455
sudo reboot
```